# vim, FreeBSD and nodemon

Tags: node.js, vim, freebsd, nodemon

- vim Version: 8.0.1638
- FreeBSD Version: 11.1.-RELEASE in VirtualBox
- nodemon Version: 1.17.3
- node Version: 9.11.1

Something strange happens! I have a simple expressJS application. Infact it is of type "Hello World". When I start it using nodemon:

`nodemon app.js`

Everything seems fine at first.

- touch app.js, nodemon restart
- touch app.js, nodemon restart
- touch app.js, nodemon restart

... and so on...

`nano app.js`

- save file, nodemon restart
- save file, nodemon restart
- save file, nodemon restart

`vim app.js`

- save file, nodemon restart
- save file again (with or without changes) -> no more restarts until I manually restart nodemon

Filesystem is ZFS. I need to use the nodemon -L option to make things work with vim. Any idea?

-- Thomas

Comment: [immortal](https://immortal.run/post/run.yml/) works in a similar way only, every time the service `file.yml` is modified it restarts the service, just in case you could give a try creating a  `run.yml` file and edit it with vim  to see if you get the same (no restart) behavior